# angular mocke2e, how to send real ajax, not caught by httpbackend

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock

angular mocke2e, how to send real ajax, not caught by httpbackend?
I may want to send both mock and real ajax in my development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can passThrough any call came into httpBackend with its inbuilt method.

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('AnyCall.html').passThrough();
```

[More reference link.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend)